# How to run 3 dependent application at same time

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

i am running 3 application at same time in different console , all 3 application are dependent to each other. 
For example three application cmd , sys, rts.
cmd : here we give user inputs (instruction) .
sys : here the setup(application) is ready according to the user inputs means it decide what operation is performed according to user inputs.
rts : here the mai functioning  is  happening.

My question is how can i run all application continuously in one console (cmd) , other application is run in background if it takes the inputs?????

Means how to write a scripts to run all 3 application execute.

Comment: Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). Perhaps you want to start some program in the background with `&` or using the [nohup(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) or [batch(1)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) commands. You should explain how your programs are communicating or synchronizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run your script in background with linux `nohup` command.

```
nohup applicationName &
```